# How do I call a function after the WPF Webbrowser navigates?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have looked online for a navigation event but I didn't see a way to implement this. Certainly I must be missing something, does anyone know how to call a function right after the WPF webbrowser navigates to a new page each time it navigates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming by `how to call a function` you are talking about C# methods? In that case, you can simply register to the `Navigated` event of the `WebBrowser` control and call your function when the method is invoked:

```
 <WebBrowser Navigated="WebBrowser_Navigated"></WebBrowser>
```

And in the code-behind:

```
private void WebBrowser_Navigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    // Call your function
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you're looking for the `Navigated` event: [MSDN WebBrowser.Navigated Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.navigated%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the `Navigating` and `Navigated` events?

XAML (WPF Application):

```
<WebBrowser Name="browser" Navigated="browser_Navigated" Navigating="browser_Navigating" />
```

C# (Code behind):

```
// When navigation is done
private void browser_Navigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Navigated");
}

// When navigation starts
private void browser_Navigating(object sender, NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Navigating");
}
```